# Efficient inserting of multiple rows using defaults in SQLAlchemy Core

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am using SQLAlchemy Core. I have a table declaration with many `nullable=False, default=...` columns.

My source data rows have different columns present, exactly like in the 
[A value is required for bind parameter  (in parameter group )](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/errors.html#a-value-is-required-for-bind-parameter-x-in-parameter-group-y) section of the docs.

I'd like to fill in all the missing values using the default= definitions.

This doesn't work, raising the linked error.

The only workaround I found was to insert by single rows in a for loop. This works however it's quite slow.

How could I use executemany-like statements (with a list-of-dicts) to insert multiple rows, while filling in their missing values on the client side?

Comment: Are all your defaults client-side (e.g. `default=0`) or are some of them SQL server-side (e.g. `default=func.now()`)? Would you mind providign a short example?

Comment: All of them are client side, and simple like `default=list()` or `default=dict()`